# Database is not deleted after I uninstall app in mobile phone

Tags: android, database, caching, uninstallation

I have an android app that uses sqlite. It works well in the past. Currently I uninstall the app and reinstall again. And the old data was not deleted.
In addition, I want to know about the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE PERMISSOIN in android 13+.

In which case such thing might occur?

Answer (score 1):

That could have several reason on why it is happening.

**Check your data backup,**

theres an android feature that use auto backup. it could be backing up your SQLite db. To disable this you can add the `android:allowBackup="false"` in your `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest`.

```
<application
    ...
    android:allowBackup="false">
    ...
</application>
```

**It maybe saved on your External Storage**,
It wont be deleted if its saved on your external storage. Starting on API level 29(Android 10) above you should use Scoped Storage.

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Permission is **deprecated** in most cases since `android 11 (level 30 API)` Scoped Storage is recommended on Android13+